# Mental health vs mental illness

Tags: mental-health

What is the difference between mental health and mental illness?

What are prime examples of each category and why is a disorder such as bipolar both classified under both mental health and mental illness?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @CareyGregory Mental health and mental illness are often used interchangeably but have different meanings. I was asking why some disorders such as bipolar is sometimes said to be a mental health issue or sometimes said to be a mental illness

Comment: A "mental health issue" is an informal layman's term with no precise meaning.

Comment: Would you like to go to the hospital mental health unit for an appointment or to the mental illness unit?

Comment: @CareyGregory I was referring to the term 'mental health'. Not ' mental health issue'.

Answer (score 1):

Mental health is the term used for the field that includes mental illnesses.  They aren't exclusive or opposing terms, they're used differently.

https://www.mentalhealth.gov/basics/what-is-mental-health

Comment: A very basic answer because anything beyond that is not clearly asked by the question.